# Send values to a PHP page using Arduino ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno

I still a noob, and I'm learning Arduino. I built a PHP page to send values using GET parameters.

I would like to send a specific value from Arduino to that PHP page. I bought an ESP8266, and I would like to see it working.

I found this code and I made some changes there, but the the code is not working. I don't receive any value on my database. Can you guys help me?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(10, 11);
String cmd;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
  Serial.println("Started");
  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  esp8266.begin(115200);
  esp8266.write("AT\r\n");
}

void loop() {
  if (esp8266.available()) {
    Serial.write(esp8266.read());
    teste();
  }
  if (Serial.available()) {
    esp8266.write(Serial.read());
  }
}

void teste(){
  // Connect to the server
  esp8266.write("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"http://bubu.esy.es\",80\r\n");
  //make this command: AT+CPISTART="TCP","192.168.88.35",80
  //wait a little while for 'Linked'
  delay(300);

  //This is our HTTP GET Request change to the page and server you want to load.
  cmd = "GET /teste.php?test=5 HTTP/1.0\r\n";
  cmd += "Host: http://bubu.esy.es\r\n\r\n";
  //The ESP8266 needs to know the size of the GET request
  esp8266.write("AT+CIPSEND=");
  esp8266.write(cmd.length());
  esp8266.write("\r\n");
  esp8266.write("GET /teste.php?test=5 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: http://bubu.esy.es\r\n\r\n");
  esp8266.write("AT+CIPCLOSE\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should tell the ESP8266 to connect to your WiFi access point. You have about 10% of the required code there.

Comment: teste.php?test=5 - does this works (writes to DB) when opened by browser?

Answer (score 0):

`Host: http://bubu.esy.es` needs to be `Host: bubu.esy.es`.

Comment: Why build up cmd and then write the string out rather than cmd??  i.e. `esp8266.write("GET /teste.php?test=5 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: http://bubu.esy.es\r\n\r\n");` should be `esp8266.write(cmd);`